# Keep Getting an error in javascript about a node

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, javascript-objects

so im trying to make a list of the input from the user and i keep getting this error

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ToDo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<label>Enter What You Have To Do:</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="toDo">
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="myButton">Submit</button><br>
<ul id="list"></ul>


<script src="todojs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {
const doIt = document.getElementById('toDo').value;
const li ='<li>' + doIt + '</li>';
document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
document.getElementById('toDo').value = '';
}
```

Error
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at document.getElementById.onclick

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild` expects a `Node` Element. You are passing a string.
If you want to append a string, you can use the `insertAdjacentHTML` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {
    const doIt = document.getElementById('toDo').value;
    const li ='<li>' + doIt + '</li>';
    document.getElementById('list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
    document.getElementById('toDo').value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML(doIt);
```

should do the trick instead of the one liner

Answer (score 0):

if you pass a string, that string isn't a `node` or a real element present in the DOM, it wouldn't work.

so simply just programmatically create one element! using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

change the text inside it, using [`document.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

> try to not use `innerHTML` because is DANGEROUS, someone can insert in the input some malicious code scripts. `textContent` is more safe

one more thing, use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
instead of `.onclick`, 
because if you have more event listener in one time, `.onclick` sometimes don't work, 
 with `.addEventListener()` you can make 2 or more events work in one time.

---

for inserting before you can use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore , just read the documentation I linked to you, and you are done!

I hope this help you!

---

**one more thing:**
if you want more custom UI,

you can write a copy of all your elements inside a `<div>`, 
and then insert it inside a `<template>` tag manually...

the result is: now you have a reusable component with just regular `HTML, JS`

so the previus `document.createElement();` it will become [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
let list = document.getElementById('list');
let inputEl = document.getElementById('toDo');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const getliValue = inputEl.value;

  const newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.textContent = getliValue;
  list.appendChild(newLi);

  inputEl.value = '';
});
```

```html
<h1>To Do List</h1>

<label>Enter What You Have To Do:</label>
<br><br>

<input type="text" id="toDo">
<br><br>

<button type="button" id="myButton">Submit</button>
<br>

<ul id="list"></ul>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```